# Creating a backup batch script

Tags: batch-file, backup, xcopy, rar

I'm trying to create a backup batch script. Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set drive=E:\zaloha\Backup
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /e /h /y /q /i

echo ### Copying the files...

%backupcmd% "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6jmi87vr.default\jetpack\jid1-xUfzOsOFlzSOXg@jetpack\simple-storage\store.json" "%drive%\RES_Settings"
%backupcmd% "h:\downloads\アニメ\descript.ion" "%drive%\TC\アニメ"

echo ### Packing the archive...

"d:\programy\winrar\rar.exe" a -r -m5 -agYYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS -df "%drive%\backup_.rar" "%drive%"

echo ### Done!
@pause
```

Though I've got several problems with it:
 1) At the first file, it always asks `Does ... specify a file name or directory name on the target (
F = file, D = directory)?`. I tried searching in documentation for xcopy, and I thought /i switch should suppress it, but it doesn't. How do I make xfile copy it without questions?

2) At the second file, it states `File not found - descript.ion 0 File(s) copied`. The file is definitely there. It has archived and hidden attributes, but I thought that /h switch should cover that.

3) When creating an archive, it archives the entire file path from the root folder of my disk. How do I tell rar.exe to create folder path only locally?

Answer (score 0):

These are hints for you to search for more information, not a full solution.

1) if you are copying a single file then use the `copy` command

2) You have foreign characters in your path and you will need to deal with them, as code pages and unicode may be the issue.

3) Rar should have a switch to use explicit paths or not.